# Facebook Graph user pictures

Tags: php, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api

I'm using PHP for a login system with facebook but it won't get the uploaded images from a Facebook profile, only the profile picture and the normal things from facebook like email and user ID

```
<?php

/* INCLUSION OF LIBRARY FILEs*/
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/GraphUser.php' );
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php');
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php');

/* USE NAMESPACES */

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\FacebookCurl;

/*PROCESS*/

//Stat Session
 session_start();

//check if users wants to logout
 if(isset($_REQUEST['logout'])){
    unset($_SESSION['fb_token']);
 }

//Use app id,secret and redirect url 
$app_id = '****';
$app_secret = '*****';
$redirect_url='http://www.url.com/index.php';

//Initialize application, create helper object and get fb sess
 FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id,$app_secret);
 $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);
 $sess = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

 //check if facebook session exists
if(isset($_SESSION['fb_token'])){
    $sess = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['fb_token']);
    try{
        $sess->Validate($id, $secret);
    }catch(FacebookAuthorizationException $e){
        print_r($e);
    }
}

$loggedin = false;
//get email as well with user permission
$login_url = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('email, user_birthday, user_likes, user_friends, user_website, user_photos'));
//logout
$logout = 'http://url.com/index.php';

//if fb sess exists echo name 
    if(isset($sess)){
        //store the token in the php session
        $_SESSION['fb_token']=$sess->getToken();
        //create request object,execute and capture response
        $request = new FacebookRequest($sess,'GET','/me');
        // from response get graph object
        $response = $request->execute();
        $graph = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::classname());
        // use graph object methods to get user details
        $id = $graph->getId();
        $firstname = $graph->getFirstName();
        $lastname = $graph->getLastName();
        $name = $graph->getName();
        $email = $graph->getProperty('email');
        $image = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$id.'/picture?width=64&height=64';
        $userphoto = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$id.'/photos/uploaded';
        $loggedin  = true;
```

The `$userphoto` variable is the one who needs to show al the uploaded photos from an user, but this one wont show any of my pictures. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all those additional permissions don´t work, you are most likely not trying with an App developer and the permissions are not approved by Facebook. Most permissions need to get approved before they can be used - else they will only work for people with a role in the App (Admin/Developer/Tester):

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

If that is not the problem, try to check if the permissions are set correctly by putting the Access Token in the debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ - If the permissions don´t show up, there´s something wrong with the login process.

One more idea, you may not use getLoginURL correctly:

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes',
  'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.myapp.com/post_login_page'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/

Btw, i suggest using the included autoloader instead of all those countless require-statements.

Comment: First thanks for your comment, but you say they will only work for people with a role in the app with admin or developer, i`m admin of the app but i dont see any of my pictures showing in there?

Comment: i´ve edited my answer, please check the access token in the debugger.

Comment: When i fill in my url adress then he dont show anything about permissions or somthing like that?

Comment: url adress? you need to fill in your access token, as i said.

Comment: anyway, the login code may not be correct, see my edited answer. just found out that you don´t use the scope parameter correctly.

Comment: $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params); He cant find this one, yeah ive never worked with facebook before so its all new for me.

Comment: only take a look at the params array. you just use a simple array, but you need to use an array with the "scope" field.

Comment: btw, the php sdk is not easy for beginners, and i recommend using the javascript sdk for login anyway. it´s much easier to handle.